# Start and Stop FTP site in scheduled task using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, ftp, scheduled-tasks

I have two PowerShell scripts to start and stop an FTP site in IIS.

StartFTP.ps1:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
(get-Website -Name "FTP").ftpserver.start()
```

StopFTP.ps1

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
(get-Website -Name "FTP").ftpserver.stop()
```

Both do what they should do when I start them in PowerShell. I created two scheduled tasks to run these jobs, my intention is to have a short time frame to get some backup files automatically to my local NAS.

In the Action part of the scheduled task, I entered

```
powershell.exe
```

as the program to run and

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Scripts\StartFTP.ps1
```

as the parameter. The task runs as it should, it starts the FTP server at the given time. I did the same for the stop script.

The jobs run under the SYSTEM account, with highest privileges.

When I start any of these tasks manually, it starts/stops the FTP site. But when they run automatically at the given time, only the start script starts the FTP site (I find the backups on my local NAS then), but the stop script does not stop it. Both tasks show (0x0) as the result code. When I look at the server in the morning, the FTP site is still running.

I can't find anything in the Windows event log.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: According to my test, I found that both the start command and the stop command can be executed normally. If the stop command is executed directly, will the FTP site stop?

Comment: It stops when I run the script in PowerShell. It also stops when I run the job from the Scheduled Tasks Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I double- and triple-checked all the settings in the stop task, and everything seemed to be OK. The start task was set to x:00, and the stop task to x:55.

Then I realized in the task overview that "Next runtime" was set to x-1:55, so the stop task was obviously running 5 minutes before the start task. I re-checked the schedule, but there was still x:55.

I deleted the schedule and re-created it, now everything works fine.